# Why does this snippet cause a leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uibarbuttonitem, reactive-cocoa

I have a class method:

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)navItemWhichAddsNewAction{
    UIBarButtonItem* addActionButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_add"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    addActionButton.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
        return [RACSignal empty];
    }];
    return addActionButton;
}
```

Then, in `–viewDidLoad`, I assign the result of this method to the right button of the `navigationItem`:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [MyClass navItemWhichAddsNewAction];
```

If I then profile the app with *Instruments*, the `rac_command` block above is always reported as allocated even when the view controller (and the navigation controller) is deallocated.

Why?

Comment: what is `rac_command`? could you please post the entire related `UIBarButtonItem` category as well, please?

Comment: rac_command is part of ReactiveCocoa (reactivecocoa.io).

Comment: have you asked the author of that framework about this issue yet?

Comment: Yes, I've posted it on their github issues page and I also tagged it with reactive-cocoa here, hopefully there are some RAC devs here as well ;).

Comment: RAC implements a few common objects -- `[RACSignal empty]`, `[RACUnit defaultUnit]`, some others -- as singletons in release builds to reduce unnecessary allocations. As a result, those objects are never deallocated in the lifetime of your app, which can make it *look* like you're leaking a signal. If you call `[MyClass navItemWhichAddsNewAction]` ten times, do you wind up with ten signals sticking around, or just the one?

Comment: I think you might be right there. I never thought that [RACSignal empty] might return a singleton, but of course it probably does :).
But then it also retains the block, doesn't it ?

Comment: If I re-create the view controller multiple times, used memory keeps increasing, and this block (plus a lot of other allocations created by RAC) are shown as persistent in each new marked generation.

Comment: @Florin Hmmmm. This is beyond my ability to diagnose. Are you sure that's from this method? I don't see anything wrong with it -- that block is retained as long as the `RACCommand` is retained, which is retained as long as the `UIBarButtonItem` is around, which is in normal country. Is it possible you're not tearing down the view hierarchy properly?

Comment: Yeah, I know, I've spent the last two days on this. I use this pattern for navItems a lot and the signal blocks instantiate view controllers, but these things are always shown as persistent each time I open and close a VC. In this simple case, no other objects are leaking, just this single block plus a bunch of allocations inside RAC (shown as <non-object> in Instruments).

Answer (score 0):

Signal doesn't complete, and leak may be caused by this. Another side-effect may be that action is not called second time because of this.